# Can anyone direct me to further information on the "Actions" choice on the Excel Options Add-Ins menu?

Tags: excel

I have noticed the "Actions" choice on the 2013 add-ins menu but the term "actions" is too general for me to find any further information. What kind of Excel Add-In is an "Actions" add-in? Where can I go to learn more?

Answer (score 0):

The Actions choice opens the dialog with the settings for AutoCorrect, autoformat, etc. with the "Actions" tab the active one. Clicking on "More Actions" leads to a MS Office 2010 article

http://office.microsoft.com/en-nz/providers/available-actions-HA001050482.aspx

I presume they have not created a 2013 version because nothing has changed. Clicking through the links in that article leads to a page about smart tags in Word 2003.